# react-native style tag "can't find variable" error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to style a text element in my component, and when attempting to apply style tag "**textStyle**", I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

// Create a Component

const Header = () => {
  return <Text style={textStyle}>Albums!</Text>;
};

const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
};
export default Header;
```

Comment: You are missing styles, <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Albums!</Text>;

Comment: You are right! that did it, maybe you should post it as an answer :) 
on a side note, do you know what's required to omit styles and just use {textStyle} as I originally used?  I think it will make the code cleaner

Comment: I found that actually is possible if you add a constructor as follows:
const {textStyle} = styles;  then when using <Text style={textStyle}>Album</Text>; it works!

Comment: I recommend you having a loot at [React-native StyleSheet](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html) for cleaner solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing **styles**, see following block of code:

```
const Header = () => {
  return <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Albums!</Text>;
};
```